# Manage Credentials option is not available even after installing Jenkins Credential plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

[image]I am really new to Jenkins and I have tried to install Credentials Plugin. But I was unable to view the **Manage Credentials option** even after installing this plugin. I am following a tutorial mentioned in the below link related to Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin installation. In the tutorial it shows the **Manage Credentials option** but I cannot see it even after installing Credentials Plugin.

http://www.tothenew.com/blog/jenkins-parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/

Can anybody please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You initially need to add a "domain" under "Credentials" in the main Menu. Once a domain is added you can add credentials under it. Now you will be able to import these credentials in Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin. Let me know if that helps.

[Add Domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RPmE.png)

Comment: Krishan this was helpful and I added a domain but still I cannot see where to store username/password of the remote server.

Comment: Likewise it mentions the credentials can only be used with docker servers.

Comment: Once you click on Credentials->Domain Name. You will see the option to add the credentials. you need to change the 'kind' of credentials you want to store. It should have an option "username with password".

Comment: Thanks Krishan for your comment. I have added a screen shot. There you can see the options available for me. Please re correct me if I made it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. It seems like you are on the Add domain page. Please add this domain in the system with Domain Name only. Once added you will see options to add credentials under this domain.

Comment: Thanks Krishan I found it and added the Credentials as you mentioned. I get 403 error when trying to build.